# Как получить количество найденных строк в выборке из oracle на php

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

Пытаюсь сделать выборку из вьюхи в оракле по линк.
Так все работает, id я получаю

```
$sql='SELECT
decode(i."ID", null, 0, i."ID") "id"
FROM dbo.DevelopmentReestr_Jobs@dir49_tw.world i WHERE
i."TaskStartDate" BETWEEN trunc(to_date(\'02.01.2016\',\'dd.mm.yyyy\')) AND trunc(to_date(\'12.01.2016\', \'dd.mm.yyyy\'))';

$_sql = oci_parse($connection, $sql);
oci_execute($_sql);
while (oci_fetch($_sql)) {
$ID=ociresult($_sql, "id"); echo $ID;
}
```

но как только заменяю выгружаемый параметр на count работать перестает

```
$sql='SELECT
count(*) as "g_count"

FROM dbo.DevelopmentReestr_Jobs@dir49_tw.world i WHERE
i."TaskStartDate" BETWEEN trunc(to_date(\'02.01.2016\', \'dd.mm.yyyy\')) AND trunc(to_date(\'20.01.2016\', \'dd.mm.yyyy\'))';

$_sql = oci_parse($connection, $sql);
oci_execute($_sql);

while (oci_fetch($_sql)) {
$ID=ociresult($_sql, "g_count"); echo $ID;
}
```

Может нужно как то декодировать? В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: что возвращает oci_fetch($_sql) ?

Comment: к сожалению пустой массив... вылез из ситуация только, добавив еще один параметр в select...

Comment: попробуй count(nvl(i."ID",0))

Comment: @user3710480 Попробуйте выполнить запрос просто в sqlplus и посмотрите, что вернёт.